# SQL adding numbers column

Tags: t-sql

Let's say I have a table:

```
Table1
ID | Table2_ID | Title
1   1           Breaking_Bad
2   1           Breaking_Bad
3   2           Simpsons
4   1           House_Of_Cards
```

I want to rename the title by adding '_XX' (where XX is a number) to only to those entries that are the same title and have the same Table2_ID. 
So end results would be

```
Table1
ID | Table2_ID | Title
1   1           Breaking_Bad_01
2   1           Breaking_Bad_02
3   2           Simpsons
4   1           House_Of_Cards
```

How could I do this with TSQL?

Comment: you need something like RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY title ORDER BY title)  + format for 2 digit number and of cause concatenate only when rank is more then 1 over the group

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Table2_ID, Title)                 AS Cnt,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Table2_ID, Title ORDER BY ID) AS RN
         FROM   Table1)
UPDATE T
SET    Title = Title + '_' + FORMAT(RN, 'D2')
WHERE  Cnt > 1;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5839b7/10/0)

Or if you are on a version without `FORMAT`

```
SET    Title = Title + CASE WHEN RN < 10 THEN '_0' ELSE '_' END + CAST(RN AS VARCHAR(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work in SQL Server?  The padding to 2 digits would be straightforward.

```
UPDATE TABLE1 A SET TITLE = TITLE + '_' + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1 B WHERE A.TITLE=B.TITLE AND A.ID<=B.ID) WHERE A.ID IN (SELECT B.ID FROM TABLE1 B 
WHERE A.Id<>B.ID and A.TITLE=B.TITLE)
```

Comment: This will set the title to `Breaking_Bad_XX` not  `Breaking_Bad_01` etcetera as the OP wants. The XX should be a sequence number

Comment: Misunderstood...I'll delete

Comment: I changed it a bit

Comment: And it still doesn't work... I've fixed some syntax issues and this is the result http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5839b7/8/0

Comment: It doesn't quite work, plus you're updating all rows, not just the ones with duplicate titles, but I removed my downvote as the idea is sort of right.

Comment: Another tweak added

Comment: Did you test this in SQL Fiddle?

Comment: Still new to the site...not familiar...will do that on the future